# Get value from fetch in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, fetch

I try to pass an array of object from localhost:5000/users to Table component as a prop but I can't.

I can fetch data from localhost:5000/users and when I try to do console.log inside it, I can see data. But when I try to do console.log outside fetch function, it returns an empty array.

The question is how can I pass the data to Table component if the data is not visible outside the fetch function ?

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Table from './Table';

function App() {

    let obj = [];

    fetch('http://localhost:5000/users')
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        return obj = data;
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(obj); // Here it returns correct data from localhost:5000/users
        return obj;
    });

    console.log(obj); // But right here, it returns an empty array

    return (
        <div>
            <Table data={obj} /> {/* The question is how can I pass data from localhost:5000/users to Table component ? */}
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `state` and `useEffect` [state in React.js](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) .
I would recommend to invest more time on `useState` and `useEffect`. To do so React.js official documentation is good source to study. Here is also some resource links: [how to use useState](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-react-setstate/#:~:text=When%20the%20request%20to%20setState,elements%20of%20the%20previous%20tree.) 
[how to use useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Table from './Table';

function App() {

    const [obj, setObj] = useState([])

      useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:5000/users")
          .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((data) => {
            //return obj = data;
            setObj(data); // setting obj using setObj
          })
          .then(() => {
            console.log(obj); // Here it returns correct data from localhost:5000/users
            return obj;
          });
      }, []);


    console.log(obj); // But right here, it returns an empty array

    return (
        
             {/* The question is how can I pass data from localhost:5000/users to Table component ? */}
        
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi Ruhul, thank you for your advise. I followed your step by using useState and useEffect but what happens is that it always returns an empty array. Both inside and outside the fetch function. Can you advise what should I do ?

Comment: You should get you data using `data.results`. I would recommend to check you API. You can use Postman to make sure your API is working. https://www.postman.com/

Comment: Thank you very much. The array does not appear because my API did not return the right value. Now I can get what I want. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be : Create a state inside a constructor in your class.

Now when you fetch, setState the data inside your state :)

Now if you create a function outside your fetch it can be like this

```
onClick = () => {
   console.log(this.state.data)
}
```

Now, you can do what you want with your data on all your component :)
And if you want to use the same component for many data, your state need to be an array, and you need to map your state :)

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because the fetch API call is a promise, therefore, the second console.log `console.log(obj); // But right here, it returns an empty array` runs before the promise resolves.

You can use state and useEffect as mentioned by Rahul Amin. I have created a js fiddle you can checkout. here. https://jsfiddle.net/titbetegya/owk7eg2a/18/