# Page render in recursive loop throws Error: Too many re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have page with few forms components as defined below, everything in front works fine, however if I look my console logs the function `Fetchmovies` is continuously being executed and throws

```
caught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

Even without error this is undesirable I don't want to make hundreds of calls to the API `url`. My requirment is just to call the `Fetchmovies` function once the page loads first time and update `Autocomplete` component with the returning array. ButI am not sure, why my page is rendered recursively.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function GetMovies() {
  var [movies_list, setMovies_list] = useState([]);

  async function Fetchmovies() {

    try {
      movies_list = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'authorization':'token'
        },
      }).then(response => movies_list = response.json());
      console.log(movies_list);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
  Fetchmovies().then(setMovies_list(movies_list));

  return (
    <Card>
      <Divider />
      <CardContent>
            <Autocomplete
              id='movies'
              name='movies'
              getOptionLabel={(movies_list) => movies_list.service_name}
              multiple
              options={movies_list}
              renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label='Impacted movies:' />}
            />
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );

}
export default GetMovies;
```

Comment: Just use [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) hook to call it only once on launch like `useEffect(() => {Fetchmovies().then(setMovies_list(movies_list));}, [])`, Just spending little effort to search in google you could easily get this answer.

Comment: It rerenders because every time it renders it triggers a new request, which triggers a new render, which ... The solution is the same one you [keep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76271306/fetching-json-from-an-url-and-store-it-as-a-list#comment134500383_76271306) being [given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76274992/how-to-update-the-list-of-options-of-an-autocomplete-component-after-its-renderi#comment134506565_76274992).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
Fetchmovies().then(setMovies_list(movies_list));
```

updates state ... which causes the component to reload .. which calls Fetchmovies again etc.

Wrap your Fetchmovies call un a [useEffect](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useeffect.asp) hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    Fetchmovies().then(setMovies_list(movies_list));
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `useEffect` but there are some errors on your fetch and the use of state.

Check here what you can do instead:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function GetMovies() {
  var [movies_list, setMovies_list] = useState([]);

  async function Fetchmovies() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'authorization':'token'
        },
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      setMovies_list(data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    Fetchmovies();
  }, [])

  return (
    <Card>
      <Divider />
      <CardContent>
            <Autocomplete
              id='movies'
              name='movies'
              getOptionLabel={(movies_list) => movies_list.service_name}
              multiple
              options={movies_list}
              renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label='Impacted movies:' />}
            />
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );

}
export default GetMovies;
```